# Getting error for "[FIRAuth auth] signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting error for "[FIRAuth auth] signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion". The error is "**Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(FIRUser *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nullable)(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)'**"

[image]

I am search a lot but didn't get any related answer. I am facing this error after updating firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says exactly what's wrong. You can copy types from the second part of your error and paste to your code.

In this case replace `FIRUser` with `FIRAuthDataResult`

Generally, use code completion. It would suggest you the correct block signature.

Comment: You are my savior man. Thank you very much. Have been struck with issue for a week and your answer solved my problem.